# Day-flight from Reykjavík to any european city

Tags: air-travel, iceland, flight-status, reykjavik

Im travelling to Reykjavík because of my job. I'll leave from Rome and of course have to come back to it.

Looking at the way back flight I saw that several sites make me leave Reykjavík during the night, and in the best of the options the travel will turn into a 13 hours nightmare.

In any case I can consider:

1. Creating and composing the travel path by myself, which in this case could turn out to be much better than leaving the web application decide for me
2. Make an intermediate stop for one day.

Either cases, I want to take a daily flight  (let's say between 9AM and 19PM) from Reykjavík to any well connected European city.

So, which are the most common flight lines from Reykjavík? 
Could you provide a site or a map or a timetable which can help me in organizing my travel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most frequent flights from Reykjavik are to London and Copenhagen.

Some possibilities for an overnight stay other than London or Copenhagen are Paris, Amsterdam, Oslo or Stockholm.

You can see a list of airlines that fly to Reykjavik on this page:
http://www.kefairport.is/English/Service/Airlines/

Link to the website of the KEF airport: http://www.kefairport.is/english/

Some other sites that could be helpful for planning the trip:

- [momondo.com](http://momondo.com)
- [dohop.com](http://dohop.com)
- [kayak.com](http://kayak.com)

Answer (score 5):

I've flown to Iceland 7 times in the last 4 years from London and have always used one of the following airlines

- [Iceland air](http://www.icelandair.co.uk/)
- [Wow](http://www.wowiceland.co.uk/) (formally Iceland Express)

Iceland Air is the better carrier - more legroom, en flight entertainment, luggage included etc.  Whereas Wow is the budget option and you have to pay for everything (booking, paying by credit card, luggage) and there is less leg room and no entertainment.

For combining flights I've always found [expedia](http://www.expedia.co.uk/) to be very good.

One thing worth bearing in mine with Iceland is the international airport is in Keflavik which is about an hours drive away from the capital itself.  There is an airport in the city itself but its only used for domestic flights.